# Sending Email from Java with JavaMail

Tags: java, unix, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I've got two Unix servers that each execute the same code to send e-mails using the JavaMail API to send an email to a given address.

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(getSession());
msg.setFrom(fromAddress);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddresses);
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddresses);

Transport.send(msg);
```

This works perfectly on one of the servers, however, not on the other. I know the problem on the second server is that, in its environment, mail needs to go through a given relay in order to actually be sent and ***I can send emails from the server directly just fine using SendMail***. So my question is, is there any way I can send email, using Java code, so that my code will be able to send e-mails on BOTH servers?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can send email on that one server using sendmail, configure JavaMail running on that server to send to sendmail running on that server.  You may need to configure sendmail to support relaying depending on what addresses you're using in your message.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to provide more details on what's failing where, with what error messages.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors - it simply doesn't send the email at all. The IT dept told me "Use mail to send through sendmail.
If you are using something else that’s trying to send directly it will not work.  Mail needs to go through a relay in this environment." which isn't overly helpful, I know...

Comment: So, use JavaMail to send it through the local sendmail.